# Return product collection which are not in cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to get product details which are not in cart. For this I am doing this way. But it returns the product details that are in cart also. But I dont want the product details that are in cart.

For cart details:

```
 $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $cartprodid[] = $item->getProductId();
        }
```

For product collection:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();   
$grandTotal=$quoteData['grand_total'];
                 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
                 $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');    
                 $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
                                               array('attribute'=>'entity_id', array("nin"=>array($cartprodid))),
                                               ))
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                            ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
                 $collection->setOrder('sku', 'ASC');
```

But I am unable to solve this. Can any one suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are on the right track.
Try using `addAttributeToFilter` instead of `addFieldToFilter`. I mean like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');    
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin'=>$cartprodid))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$collection->setOrder('sku', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Yes marius. You are right. I am on right track. Before I use to compare array with SKU. Then I am unable to get as required. After trying comparision with entity_id, I got the output as required. I forgot just to clear the browser cache. Thanks for ur quick reply. I got confidence after ur reply only.. Thanks.